# How to express fitted ARIMA model output by a mathematical equation?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I have fitted an ARIMA model to forecast GDP using the `auto.arima` function in R:

```
 Series: tGDPdev 
 ARIMA(2,0,2)(1,1,0)[12] with drift 

 Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2      ma1     ma2     sar1
       1.7038  -0.7521  -1.3467  0.5857  -0.4793
 s.e.  0.2523   0.2290   0.2180  0.0917   0.0842
        drift
       0.5334
 s.e.  0.0470
```

I would need to know the equation thath represents this model, though I'm not a mathematician. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a duplicate of several earlier posts. I have linked one, but you will find a few (or a dozen) more if you search for "ARIMA" and "equation" or something like that. You could also check the free online textbook ["Forecasting: Principles and Practice"](https://otexts.org/fpp2/) by Hyndman and Athanasopoulos, they have a chapter on this.

Comment: True, but this question is specific. Before posting this question I had already read these answers. Alas, I couldn't apply the principles to this result. I don't think that it's just replacing the coefficients in the general equation.